# ASP.NET Core Identity - end sesion on browser close and handeling that event

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-identity

Is there any way to handle a user closing the browser so by that ending his identity session and handling that event to add a logout date to the user's  logs.

the main reason is auditing (user logs). start date (when the user logs in) - end date (when the user logs out or closes the browser)

I tried using `onbeforeunload` js event, but it went wrong when the user redirects to any page the event will fire.

I tried searching `SessionEnd` asp.net core events, and determined that it is not implemented in .netcore

Can Signal R accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible or at least it will be a difficult task.

Would it be possible to set the following values:

```
ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
SlidingExpiration = true
```

..in your `app.UseCookieAuthentication` set up?
This would ensure the session is kept alive as the user is browsing around (requests are being made) but will kill the session in a short period if they are not.

Comment: actually, the main case is saving a log out date (even if the browser closed) so my latest approach is implementing it in signal r ( onConnected, onDisconnected)